# how to make disable file system routing for specific page in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How can I block file system routing for only one page in nextjs?

In spite of using Custom server, I can not apply `useFileSystemPublicRoutes : false` option because some pages is still accessed through file system router.

is there another way? or is it best to me to register every page on custom server and use `useFileSystemPublicRoutes : false` option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you public code of file next.config.js???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Temporary disable Next.js pages on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66872816/temporary-disable-next-js-pages-on-build)

Answer (score 3):

You can either use `rewrites` or `redirects` in next.config.js (Next v10.1 or above), you won't need a custom server.

You don't need to disable the `useFileSystemPublicRoutes` option, because as you said some pages should still be accessed.

let's say you have the below page folder structure:

```
pages
  ├── file_accessible.tsx
  ├── file_should_be_disabled.tsx
  ├── file_accessible_by_different_route.tsx
```

Assuming you have a 404 page, here is an example of using `redirects`

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/file_should_be_disabled',  // this path will be redirected to 404 
        destination: '/404',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/abc', 
        destination: '/file_accessible_by_different_route', // when visiting /abc, you will be redirected to this path
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Both `rewrites` and `redirects` and solve you problem, in case you also want to know the difference between `rewrites` and `redirects`:

> Rewrites act as a URL proxy and mask the destination path, making it appear the user hasn't changed their location on the site. In contrast, redirects will reroute to a new page and show the URL changes.

ref:

1. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites
2. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom server to serve that one page. So, all other pages will be served by Next.js and a specific one by the custom server. Just don't put this page to `/pages` so you won't get a routing conflict.

Comment: obviously, if you have a dynamic catch-all route, like [[...index]].js, this solution cannot work

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be renaming those routes/files from 'file.js' to just 'file' (or any other extensions as you would prefer) which will then be ignored by next.js