# Temporary disable Next.js pages on build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

There are SSR-related problems with several pages in Next.js project that results in errors on `npm run build` and prevent the project from being built:

```
pages/
  foo/
    bar/
      [id].jsx
      index.jsx
    index.jsx
  ...
```

For example, `bar`:

```
export function getStaticProps() {
  return someApiCallThatCurrentlyFails()
  ...
}

export default function Bar() {...}
```

As a quick fix, it may be convenient to just not build `bar/*.*` pages and make routes unavailable.

Can pages be ignored on Next.js build without physically changing or removing page component files in the project?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can configure the `pageExtensions` in the `next.config.js`.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  pageExtensions: ["page.js"],
}
```

After configuring this, the only pages `with *.page.js` will be considered in the below given directory structure.

```
pages/
├── user
│   └── setting
│       ├── index.js
├── _app.page.js
├── _document.page.js
├── list.page.js
└── theme.ts
```

Custom file ignores patterns that are not supported yet. You can visit the [PR](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/16464/commits/79f77c406301ee6a00f684674738151cecf762d0) created here, and the solution given [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8454#issuecomment-560432659). This is the most satisfactory solution so far.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a proper solution indeed. I guess I'll move pageExtensions value to environment variables to use it on-site.

Comment: @EstusFlask There are so many requests about this feature on the official repo. maybe next js will provide some permanent solution in upcoming releases.

Comment: Trying to figure out if `pages/_middleware.js` needs to be renamed to `pages/_middleware.pages.js` in my application. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

[@Mathilda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16193550/mathilda) Here from Nextjs docs: it's necessary for all pages including _app, _document, etc.
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions
[image]

```
Changing these values affects all Next.js pages, including the following:

- middleware.js
- pages/_document.js
- pages/_app.js
- pages/api/
For example, if you reconfigure .ts page extensions to .page.ts, you would need to rename pages like _app.page.ts.
```

Comment: Not answers the question but I appreciate the follow-up. Please, add the content as formatted text instead of an image, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution if you already have a very old project or if you didn't consider that such a thing might be needed during the implementation of the basic set of pages.

You can create custom pages in a separate folder and, under certain env conditions, redirect them to mock data using `webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`. This mock data can return `{ notFound: true }`.